# Simple VB.Net text base communication server

Tags: vb.net, sockets, server

I try for one week to provide a PHP application (client) and a VB.Net application (server) via text messages (JSON).
I must therefore open a socket server in VB.Net, read the client message and close the connection. Of course by managing connections from clients in separate threads since PHP may well send multiple queries simultaneously.

This is a trivial task in Java, as I usually do, but and a VB.Net I tried many solutions found on StackOverflow and CodeProject, but none is exactly what I want to achieve .

Comment: You should give an example of what is not exactly what you want to achieve, why, why you can't modify it, and the exact specification you require.

Comment: I found solution like that [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/307315/Reusable-multithreaded-tcp-client-and-server-class), but I'm looking for the simpliest way. Not using a hammer to kill a fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think I found something interesting !

Based on the post [Writing a Simple HTTP Server in VB.Net](http://www.santry.com/Blog/tabid/90/ID/1289/Writing-a-Simple-HTTP-Server-in-VBNet.aspx) from Patrick Santry, I have a functional class :

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Server
#Region "Declarations"
    Private Shared singleServer As Server
    Private Shared blnFlag As Boolean

    Private LocalTCPListener As TcpListener
    Private LocalPort As Integer
    Private LocalAddress As IPAddress = GetIPAddress()
    Private ServerThread As Thread
#End Region

#Region "Properties"
    Public Property ListenPort() As Integer
        Get
            Return LocalPort
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            LocalPort = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ListenIPAddress() As IPAddress
        Get
            Return LocalAddress
        End Get
    End Property
#End Region

#Region "Methods"
    Private Function GetIPAddress() As IPAddress
        With System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
            If .AddressList.Length > 0 Then
                Return New IPAddress(.AddressList.GetLowerBound(0))
            End If
        End With
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function getServer(ByVal LocalPort As Integer, ByVal Optional LocalAddress As String = Nothing) As Server
        If Not blnFlag Then
            singleServer = New Server
            If Not LocalAddress Is Nothing Then
                Server.singleServer.LocalAddress = IPAddress.Parse(LocalAddress)
            End If
            If Not LocalPort = 0 Then
                Server.singleServer.LocalPort = LocalPort
            End If
            blnFlag = True
            Return Server.singleServer
        Else
            Return Server.singleServer
        End If
    End Function

    Public Sub StartServer()
        Try
            LocalTCPListener = New TcpListener(LocalAddress, LocalPort)
            LocalTCPListener.Start()
            ServerThread = New Thread(AddressOf StartListen)
            serverThread.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub SendResponse(ByVal sData As String, ByRef thisSocket As Socket)
        SendResponse(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sData), thisSocket)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub SendResponse(ByVal bSendData As [Byte](), ByRef thisSocket As Socket)
        Dim iNumBytes As Integer = 0
        If thisSocket.Connected Then
            If (iNumBytes = thisSocket.Send(bSendData, bSendData.Length, 0)) = -1 Then
                ' socket error can't send packet
            Else
                ' number of bytes sent.
            End If
        Else
            ' connection dropped.
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub New()
        ' create a singleton
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartListen()
        Do While True
            ' accept new socket connection
            Dim mySocket As Socket = LocalTCPListener.AcceptSocket
            If mySocket.Connected Then
                Dim ClientThread As Thread = New Thread(Sub() Me.ProcessRequest(mySocket))
                ClientThread.Start()
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessRequest(ByRef mySocket As Socket)
        Dim bReceive() As Byte = New [Byte](1024) {}
        Dim i As Integer = mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0)
        Dim sRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bReceive)
        Dim sResponse As String
        sResponse = "Your message was : " & sRequest
        SendResponse(sResponse, mySocket)
        mySocket.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopServer()
        Try
            LocalTCPListener.Stop()
            ServerThread.Abort()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

It remains for me to process the request and generate the response in the processRequest method.